# How to keep characters with regular expressions that I don't want to delete in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I use this code to delete all tag elements in HTML.

```
import re
MyString = 'aaa<p>Radio and television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
MyString = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', MyString)
print(MyString)
```

The output is:

```
aaaRadio and television.very popular in the world today.Millions of people watch TV. That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%bb
```

But now I need to keep `<br>` and `<br/>`.

I want the output likes this:

```
aaaRadio and television.<br>very<br/> popular in the world today.Millions of people watch TV. That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%bb
```

How to modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture `<br>` tags separately in group1 and capture any other tag separately and replace the whole match with `\1` to retain `<br>` tags and remove rest other tags. Replace

```
(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>
```

with `\1`. Also added `(?i)` inline modifier (you can also pass `re.IGNORECASE` as fourth argument in `re.sub` to make it case-insensitive) to make the regex case insensitive for also matching it with `<BR>` or `<BR/>`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zTGLFw/2)**

Your updated Python code,

```
import re
MyString = 'aaa<p>Radio and television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular <BR>in the <BR/>world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
MyString = re.sub('(?i)(<br/?>)|<[^>]*>', r'\1', MyString)
print(MyString)
```

Prints the string with `br` tag only and rest tags removed,

```
aaaRadio and television.<br>very<br/> popular <BR>in the <BR/>world today.Millions of people watch TV. That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%bb
```

In another approach, you can also use a negative look ahead to reject tags that are `br` using this regex,

```
(?i)<(?!br/?>)[^>]*>
```

and just replace it with empty string.

**[Regex Demo using negative lookahead to reject](https://regex101.com/r/zTGLFw/3)**

Python code using negative lookahead regex,

```
import re
MyString = 'aaa<p>Radio and television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular <BR>in the <BR/>world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
MyString = re.sub('(?i)<(?!br/?>)[^>]*>', r'', MyString)
print(MyString)
```

Prints,

```
aaaRadio and television.<br>very<br/> popular <BR>in the <BR/>world today.Millions of people watch TV. That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%bb
```

Comment: Tkanks!If  I want to keep <br> and <br/> and <BR> and <BR/>,how to do it?

Comment: You can make it case insensitive, either by putting `(?i)` inline modifier before regex like this `(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>` or by passing `re.IGNORECASE` as fourthargument to `re.sub` Let me update this in my post.