# Removing tags from HTML, except specific ones (but keep their contents)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing, html-parsing

I use this code to delete all tag elements in HTML. I need to keep `<br>` and `<br/>` .
So I use this code:

```
import re
MyString = 'aaa<p>Radio and<BR> television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
MyString = re.sub('(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>',r'\1', MyString)
print(MyString)
```

The output is:

```
aaaRadio and<BR> television.<br>very<br/> popular in the world today.Millions of people watch TV. That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%bb
```

The result is right, but now I want to keep `<p>` and `</p>` and `<br>` and `<br/>` .

How can I modify my code?

Comment: You can only tag people who've interacted with *this post*, not [answered previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55917765/3001761).

Comment: All right,Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an HTML parser is much more robust than using regex. Regex should not be used to parse nested structures like HTML.

Here's a working implementation which iterates over all HTML tags and for those who are not `p` or `br`, strips them of the tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mystring = 'aaa<p>Radio and<BR> television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'

soup = BeautifulSoup(mystring,'html.parser')
for e in soup.find_all():
    if e.name not in ['p','br']:
        e.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
aaa<p>Radio and<br/> television.<br/></p><p>very<br> popular in the world today.</br></p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%</p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%</p>bb
```

Comment: But the `<span>` tag not deleted.Why?

Comment: But in your output,the `<span>` tag still exists.

Comment: Edited my code and output, sorry about that. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `regex` is the proper solution here, but since you asked:

```
import re
html = html.replace("<p>", "{p}").replace("</p>", "{/p}")
txt = re.sub("<[^>]*>", "", html)
txt = txt.replace("{p}", "<p>").replace("{/p}", "</p>")
```

I essentially change the `p` tag to another token, and replace back after removing all tags.

Parsing html with regex, is not a good idea in general.

Comment: Thanks!But how to use `re.sub('(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>',r'\1'` to modify?

Comment: just add another replacement prior to the regex, to account for `br` as well

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to modify.But the first`<p>` is missing.

My code:

```
import re
MyString = 'aaa<p>Radio and<BR> television.<br></p><p>very<br/> popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
# MyString = re.sub('(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>',r'\1', MyString)
MyString = re.sub('(?i)(<br\/?>)|<[^>]*>(<\/?p>)|<[^>]*>',r'\1\2', MyString)
print(MyString)
```

The output is:

```
aaaRadio and<BR> television.<br><p>very<br/> popular in the world today.<p>Millions of people watch TV. <p>That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%</p>and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%</p>bb
```

Comment: Is there a reason for choosing regex instead of a HTML parser?